My postgresql indexes are read slowly from disk
I have a database of sufficient size that it does not fit entirely in RAM, including indexes that also exceed RAM capacity. When performing queries, I observe significant differences in processing time depending on whether the index needs to be read from disk or is already loaded in RAM. I have confirmed using EXPLAIN ANALYZE that the issue stems from index scans. See for example :

https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/2c85077gagh98a17 : very slow because some part of the index is "read" (from disk) and not "hit".
https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/gfd20f8cadaa5261#plan/node/8 : instantaneous, when everything is in RAM.

I measured the speed of loading my index into RAM during a query, which is approximately 2 MB/s. However, my infrastructure theoretically supports disk read speeds of around 900 MB/s.
This issue appears related to the index itself rather than a disk read speed cap. For instance, when I execute 2 parallel queries on different tables, the disk read speed reaches 4 MB/s. Yet, when I execute 2 parallel queries on the same table, my disk read remains at 2 MB/s.
My question is : what can I change to reach an index reading speed from disk of 900 Mo/s ?
I am working within an Azure VM environment. If additional information is required, I am available to provide it.
Environment :

P80 disks
Postgresql 12
VM E16s_v3

The partitioned table mentioned in the first plan more or less follows this DDL
-- public."F_TDLJ_HIST_1" definition

-- Drop table

-- DROP TABLE public."F_TDLJ_HIST_1";

CREATE TABLE public."F_TDLJ_HIST_1" (
    "ID_TRAIN" int4 NOT NULL,
    "ID_JOUR" int4 NOT NULL,
    "ID_LEG" int4 NOT NULL,
    "JX" int4 NOT NULL,
    "RES" int4 NULL,
    "REV" float8 NULL,
    "CAPA" int4 NULL,
    "OFFRE" int4 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "F_TDLJ_HIST_1_OLDP_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_TRAIN", "ID_JOUR", "ID_LEG", "JX")
)
PARTITION BY RANGE ("ID_JOUR");
CREATE INDEX "F_TDLJ_HIST_1_OLDP_ID_JOUR_JX_idx" ON ONLY public."F_TDLJ_HIST_1" USING btree ("ID_JOUR", "JX");
CREATE INDEX "F_TDLJ_HIST_1_OLDP_ID_JOUR_idx" ON ONLY public."F_TDLJ_HIST_1" USING btree ("ID_JOUR");
CREATE INDEX "F_TDLJ_HIST_1_OLDP_ID_LEG_idx" ON ONLY public."F_TDLJ_HIST_1" USING btree ("ID_LEG");
CREATE INDEX "F_TDLJ_HIST_1_OLDP_ID_TRAIN_idx" ON ONLY public."F_TDLJ_HIST_1" USING btree ("ID_TRAIN");
CREATE INDEX "F_TDLJ_HIST_1_OLDP_JX_idx" ON ONLY public."F_TDLJ_HIST_1" USING btree ("JX");


-- public."F_TDLJ_HIST_1" foreign keys

ALTER TABLE public."F_TDLJ_HIST_1" ADD CONSTRAINT "F_TDLJ_HIST_1_OLDP_ID_JOUR_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("ID_JOUR") REFERENCES public."D_JOUR"("ID_JOUR");
ALTER TABLE public."F_TDLJ_HIST_1" ADD CONSTRAINT "F_TDLJ_HIST_1_OLDP_ID_LEG_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("ID_LEG") REFERENCES public."D_OD"("ID_OD");
ALTER TABLE public."F_TDLJ_HIST_1" ADD CONSTRAINT "F_TDLJ_HIST_1_OLDP_ID_TRAIN_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("ID_TRAIN") REFERENCES public."D_TRAIN"("ID_TRAIN");
ALTER TABLE public."F_TDLJ_HIST_1" ADD CONSTRAINT "F_TDLJ_HIST_1_OLDP_JX_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("JX") REFERENCES public."D_JX"("JX");

The first explain analyze plan is the "whole plan", I directly targeted a specific partition, under conditions on columns "ID_TRAIN", "ID_JOUR", "JX"
Here is a request where I tried to update random_page_cost, with the plan :
query:
set track_io_timing=TRUE; set random_page_cost = 10000000;
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS)(
    select "ID_TRAIN", "ID_JOUR", "JX", "ID_LEG", "RES", "REV" from "F_TDLJ_HIST_1" fth
    inner join "D_TRAIN" using ("ID_TRAIN")
    inner join "D_ENTNAT" using ("ID_ENTNAT")
    where "ENTITY" = 'LOIREPARIS' and "ID_JOUR" between 4770 and 4820 and "JX" between -92 and 1
);

plan:
Nested Loop  (cost=2.63..30525.21 rows=38926 width=28) (actual time=80.858..884011.228 rows=304556 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=35897 read=255071
  I/O Timings: read=879812.508
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2.07..60.13 rows=35 width=4) (actual time=0.136..1.552 rows=272 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=71
        ->  Index Scan using "UX_ENTNAT" on "D_ENTNAT"  (cost=0.27..2.49 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.058..0.060 rows=1 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (("ENTITY")::text = 'LOIREPARIS'::text)
              Buffers: shared hit=3
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on "D_TRAIN"  (cost=1.80..57.11 rows=53 width=8) (actual time=0.073..1.249 rows=272 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: ("ID_ENTNAT" = "D_ENTNAT"."ID_ENTNAT")
              Heap Blocks: exact=65
              Buffers: shared hit=68
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "fki_D_TRAIN_ID_ENTNAT_fkey"  (cost=0.00..1.78 rows=53 width=0) (actual time=0.040..0.041 rows=272 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ("ID_ENTNAT" = "D_ENTNAT"."ID_ENTNAT")
                    Buffers: shared hit=3
  ->  Index Scan using "F_TDLJ_HIST_1_OLDP_p4770_pkey" on "F_TDLJ_HIST_1_OLDP_p4770" fth  (cost=0.56..778.42 rows=9201 width=28) (actual time=4.305..3248.805 rows=1120 loops=272)
        Index Cond: (("ID_TRAIN" = "D_TRAIN"."ID_TRAIN") AND ("ID_JOUR" >= 4770) AND ("ID_JOUR" <= 4820) AND ("JX" >= '-92'::integer) AND ("JX" <= 1))
        Buffers: shared hit=35826 read=255071
        I/O Timings: read=879812.508
Settings: effective_cache_size = '96GB', effective_io_concurrency = '200', max_parallel_workers_per_gather = '4', random_page_cost = '1e+07', search_path = 'public', work_mem = '64MB'
Planning Time: 185.491 ms
Execution Time: 884168.159 ms


this is better suited for [dba.se]

I hesitated, most of my last questions on Database Administrator have not got reach, and some of the postgresql contributors are only on Stackoverflow.

Ask Azure, it's their environment and they created the problem. We had the same issue, complained and kept complaining, suddenly the problem was solved. I have no idea what the issue was. That was Azure Single Server

It would be better to see the plans themselves, not just your interpretations of them.  For an plain index scan, you can't easily separate the IO for the index from the IO for the table because a plain index scan node involves hopping back and forth between index and table and the IO is not segregated.

Thanks for the feedback @jjanes I updated my question

Can you turn on track_io_timing?  This will require admin access to do.  Also, what do you get if you force bitmap index scans, by  set enable_indexscan=off?  This should get it to report the IO separately for the index and for the table.  You would need to pick a new list of IDs to query for, so it isn't all in cache already.

You are reading 311k rows. Why do you expect this to be instantaneous?

@TheImpaler 311k rows in almost 13 minutes is really slow. An SSD on Azure should be able to do at least 1000 records per millisecond, about 311 milliseconds for this query.

The docs I read for P80 on Azure (maybe the wrong docs, I'm not an Azure user) don't say anything concrete about latency.  Unless the latency is insanely low (<0.05ms) there is no way to get 20,000 IOPS without having many IO operations in flight at the same time. But in the plan you show, PostgreSQL will not issue more than one request at the same time.
If you get it to use a bitmap scan and if you jack up effective_io_concurrency, then it will issue many requests at the same time for part of the plan, and could be much faster.
I assume the reason it didn't choose the bitmap scan is because you lowered random_page_cost to be nearly the same as seq_page_cost.  People often recommend this with SSD, but I think it is often a mistake.  While SSD does reduce the cost of random IO, it also often reduces the cost of sequential IO by a similar ratio (This depends a lot of the SSD hardware, drivers, bus, etc.).
UPDATE: based on the comments, I think your table must be highly correlated on "ID_TRAIN". That is, pg_stats.correlation for that column must be close to 1. PostgreSQL will then assume that the index scan will drive the table to be read in physical order, and will charge seq_page_cost not random_page_cost. (This will then make the bitmap scan look unattractive because the main advantage that the planner sees is to make the IO more sequential-like.  The benefit of effective_io_concurrency is real, but the planner doesn't take it into account)  But this assumption is likely a bad one. If "ID_TRAIN" has low cardinality i.e. each distinct value of it has hundreds of thousands or millions of rows, then the amount of table devoted to any given value of ID_TRAIN will be large, much too large to fit in a small number of pages.  So if the table physical ordering is not correlated on ID_JOUR after ID_TRAIN, then reading the index in order within one ID_TRAIN will still be hopping all over the table doing random IO, although the planner is unaware of this. The planner never looks at the correlation of the 2nd column in the index conditioned on the first column.
If this is the case, you options for dealing with it are limited and poor.  You could cluster the table on the index, which would put the rows into order of both (ID_TRAIN, ID_JOUR) rather than just ID_TRAIN alone. That way the assumption that most of the IO will be sequential will become true.  But doing that CLUSTER will rewrite the entire table under an exclusive lock, so it is far from a cheap operation.  Also, when the table is updated in the future, no effort is made to maintain this clustering, so it will eventually degrade.  Or you could try to tie the planner's hands by setting enable_indexscan to off--Not something I'd be eager to do as a default setting, but you could get away with it just for a few particular queries.

This issue appears related to the index itself rather than a disk read speed cap. For instance, when I execute 2 parallel queries on different tables, the disk read speed reaches 4 MB/s. Yet, when I execute 2 parallel queries on the same table, my disk read remains at 2 MB/s.

For the 2 queries on the same table, were they identical queries, with the same list of ids?  If so, they probably move through in lock step.  One makes an IO request and waits for it to finish, the other finds it needs the same data and so adds itself to wait for it to finish as well.  They both wait together, so no extra works gets done.  (If this is not the case and the id lists are really different, then I am at a loss to explain what is going on.)

Thank you for the answer ! I tried with an absurd cost number set random_page_cost = 10000000, vs 1 for sequential, and I can't get the optimizer to do anything but an index scan for my table.

@DoeJowns That's weird.  Did the plan's cost estimate change at all?  I definitely get a preference for bitmap scan with only the default value of 4.  Of course I don't have your real data so I just had to simulate it.  What if you set enable_indexscan to false?

It looks like despite the increase of random_page_cost showed in the SYSTEM part of the explain analyze i added to my question, the cost of the Index Scan is still considered very low (~700) : https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/945e41fgfe6c4dd2
